# WPF how to dispose a running operation with Task

Tags: wpf, task

I've a method which check if a directory exists or not.

```
public static bool FileExists(string path, int timeout = 500)
{
    Func<bool> func = () => File.Exists(path);
    using (Task<bool> task = new Task<bool>(func))
    {
        task.Start();
        return task.Wait(timeout) && task.Result;
    }
}
```

It works fine but when I close my wpf application, sometimes I had this exception:

*A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled)*

Any hints how to detect the exception? I tried to wrap my code into try...catch block but I think there's more elegand solution,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an overload of the `Wait` method accepts a `CancellationToken`. If you use this one, you could cancel it using a `CancellationTokenSource` as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

You don't really need to dispose the task though:

```
public static bool FileExists(string path, int timeout = 500)
{
    Func<bool> func = () => File.Exists(path);
    Task<bool> task = Task.Run(func);
    return task.Wait(timeout) && task.Result;
}
```

Stephan Toub explains more about this in his blog post:

[Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/)